# Image shrink resizing using fabric js

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I am using fabric js. After editing and saving Image it is shrinking in canvas and loosing quality.

This is code using while saving and sending through ajax call.

```
c.discardActiveGroup().renderAll();

var objs = c.getObjects().map(function(o) {
    return o.set({'active': false, hasBorders: false});
});

var group = new fabric.Group(objs, {
    originX: 'center', 
    originY: 'center',
    strokeWidth : 0
});

var cloneGroup = new fabric.Group(objs, {
    originX: 'center', 
    originY: 'center',
    strokeWidth : 0
});

cloneGroup.scaleToWidth(imgWidth-1);

var dataURL = cloneGroup.toDataURL({
    format: 'png',
    left: 1,
    top: 1,
    width: imgWidth,
    height: imgHeight
});

saveAjaxCall(dataURL, flagBit);

group._restoreObjectsState();

c.remove(cloneGroup);

c.renderAll();
```

Comment: why it is shrinking i am unable to find i am converting to base64.

Comment: I have added code while using for saving image in canvas.